# how to get shared video link in expo react native app

Tags: react-native, video, expo, sharing

When user click on share button of any video from You Tube or any other platform. and click my app from sharing list. then I want to show URL of that video in my app. (just like you see in Whatsapp or in any other app). please guide me over this for react native expo. Thanks.

I have tried These two but not working
const url = await Linking.getInitialURL();
const sharedContent = await Sharing.getSharedTextAsync();

Answer (score 0):

A standard solution should be app receives sharing intent from other apps and handle received content by MIME types (text, image, video,...) and display content with either Video Player or Image Viewer.

Note: Available packages are not supported by Expo - https://ajith-ab.github.io/react-native-receive-sharing-intent/

Comment: Do I need to use Xcode for ios dev? because i dont have mac

Comment: A new solution  emerged with Expo support  but require to compile a custom Expo  Go Client - https://github.com/achorein/expo-share-intent-demo

Comment: You can use  Expo EAS  which compiles the app in the cloud on Expo-hosted Mac.